# CMD Username variable

Tags: batch-file

there is a folder "Folder1" in

```
%SYSTEMDRIVE%/users/[username]/appdata/local/Folder/Folder1/
```

Which is in the user's folders. User names are unknown.

```
@Echo Off
Set Folder1=%SYSTEMDRIVE%/users/[username]/appdata/local/Folder/Folder1/Folder2/
IF EXIST Lotus (
  move %SYSTEMDRIVE%/users/[username]/appdata/local/Folder/Folder1/ %SYSTEMDRIVE%/users/[username]/appdata//local/
) ELSE (
  goto end
)
```

How to set `username`?

Comment: `%LOCALAPPDATA%` will give you the local app data folder.

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA% will refer to the user under which is now in the system. and I need all the ways, all the users.

Comment: How about you try to explain what you're trying to achieve? You appear to be trying to move a directory named `Folder1` up one level, should an extensionless file or directory named `Lotus` exist in the current directory! Is that correct?

Comment: Do you want a specific user (obviously not the logged-in user  according to your comment above) or all of the users or `All Users` or maybe does `Public` serve your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder names are known/static, you can get by with something as simple as:

```
for /d %%A in (%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\*) do (
    if exist "%%A\appdata\local\Folder\Folder1\Lotus" (
        move "%%A\appdata\local\Folder\Folder1\" "%%A\appdata\local\"
    )
)
```

`for /d` will just loop through the folders specified without being recursive. I'm not sure about how you have your `if` stuff setup but if you're aiming to grab user profiles, this is a simple way to do that.

Reference: [for /d](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Comment: It worked. It was easier than I thought.

`for /d %%A in (%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\*) do move "%%A\appdata\local\Folder\Folder1\Folder2" "%%A\appdata\local\Folder\"`